# howto let ruby share data beetwen a class and its subclasses in conjuction with extend

Tags: ruby, class, module, extend

```
module M

  def f=(x)
    @f= x
  end

  def f
    @f
  end

end

class A
  extend M
end

class B < A
end

A.f= 42
puts A.f
puts B.f
```

this produces

```
42
nil
```

Is @f a class variable to A and B?
How do I share a variable between A and B by only writing this into M?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By not using @@f directly, but rather class_variable_set() and class_variable_get(), class variables of A, B and C can be used from within M.

```
module M

    def f=(x)
        class_variable_set("@@f", x)
    end

    def f
        class_variable_get("@@f")
    end

end

class A
    extend M
end

class B < A
end

class C
    extend M
end

A.f= 42
C.f= 23
puts A.f
puts B.f
puts C.f
```

this produces

```
42
42
23
```

As you can see, the variables are shared by A and B, but not C.

Answer (score 0):

Class variables may do what you need here:

```
module M

  def f=(x)
    @@f= x
  end

  def f
    @@f
  end

end

class A
  extend M
end

class B < A
end

A.f= 42
puts A.f
puts B.f
```

This produces:

```
42
42
```

This seems to be closer to the behavior you want:

```
def M()
  m = Module.new
  m.module_eval <<-HERE
    def f=(x)
      @@f= x
    end

    def f
      @@f
    end
  HERE
  m
end

class A
  extend M()
end

class B < A
end

class C
  extend M()
end


A.f= 42
puts A.f
puts B.f

C.f = 23
puts C.f
puts A.f
puts B.f
```

Produces:

```
 42
 42
 23
 42
 42
```

Comment: The class variable now belongs to M and not to A or B, so it shared by all classes which are extended. But it should only be shared by all subclasses and the class itself

    module M

     @@f= nil

     def f=(x)
      @@f= x
     end

     def f
      @@f
     end

    end

    class A
     extend M
    end

    class C
     extend M
    end


    A.f= 42
    C.f= 23
    puts A.f
    puts C.f

produces

    23
    23

Comment: If you want to share data between (sub)classes like this, it's going to have to be through either a) class variables or b) trickier with hooks. An instance variable (single `@`) is never a class variable, no matter from whose perspective (they live in different places and have different scopes).

Comment: But how do I get a class variable of A by extending it with M.
Your solution creates a class variable of M and not A.

Comment: Some variety of eval is going to be the only way. Is the "must use extend" a hard and fast rule?

Comment: I want to make it a module so it can used in different classes. Extend or include are the standard way to extend classes, I'd rather use one of this, than doing some ugly stuff.

Comment: I think class_variable_set and class_variable_get, is a much clener way, than creating a seperate module with seperate methods for each class it's included. Evaluating strings where there is no need to, is also ugly.

Comment: Sounds like you already know the answer. Why ask the question then?

Comment: I didn't knew the answer at the time I asked. You helped me with your input to find it.

Answer (score 0):

B::A.f will produce the correct result

Comment: warning: toplevel constant A referenced by B::A