# Derived Class shares class variables?

Tags: ruby, inheritance

I have a class `Cache` and 2 derived classes `Foo` and `Bar` (simplification, but the principle is the same).

```
class Cache

  @@test = []

  def self.test
    @@test
  end

 def self.add(value)
   @@test << value
 end

end

class Foo < Cache
end

class Bar < Cache
end
```

Running the following leads me to conclude that the @@test is not unique to `Foo` and `Bar`, but is only unique to `Cache`, which is something I don't want nor expect.

```
Foo.add(1) #[1]
Bar.add(2) #[1,2]
puts Foo.test #[1,2]
```

Isn't this supposed to be:

```
Foo.add(1) #[1]
Bar.add(2) #[2]
puts Foo.test #[1]
```

How can I get the behaviour that I want? Why is Ruby doing this so strange?

Comment: This post should answer your question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451143/howto-let-ruby-share-data-beetwen-a-class-and-its-subclasses-in-conjuction-with-e

Comment: You can find your answers in this article: http://railstips.org/blog/archives/2006/11/18/class-and-instance-variables-in-ruby/

Comment: I started writing an example of instance members and then I reached your proof and became puzzled. Why exactly do you need class methods in this case? Your example doesn't demonstrate why creating two instances of Cache is insufficient.

Comment: Yes, you are indeed right. I could revisited my code to check up on the necessity of this way. Maybe that's indeed the easy solution, instead of making it more difficult than it apparently is in Ruby. Feel free to post this also as a solution.

Comment: Do classes Foo and Bar hold any methods of their own?

Comment: I rewrote the classes to be used as instances, and a static class to contain the references to them. This solved the problem elegantly, so thanks. Please post your comment as answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution in this case was not to use static classes, but just 2 instances of the class I wanted and storing them in a static variable.